# Can't authenticate the user, not found in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt

User is in DB created, checked the code several times, no syntax errors, just returns undefined, even tho the user is created. When making post request with name and password, typing credentials correctly either. Code:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({
      name: String,
      password: String,
    admin: Boolean
});

var Usermodel = mongoose.model("user", User);
module.exports = Usermodel;

router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {

  // find the user
  user.findOne({
    name: req.body.name
  }).then(function(err, user) {
    console.log(user);
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
    } else if (user) {

      // check if password matches
      if (user.password != req.body.password) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
      } else {

        // if user is found and password is right
        // create a token with only our given payload
    // we don't want to pass in the entire user since that has the password
    const payload = {
      admin: user.admin
    };
        var token = jwt.sign(payload, 'superSecret', {
          expiresIn: 60*60*24 // expires in 24 hours
        });

        // return the information including token as JSON
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Enjoy your token!',
          token: token
        });
      }

    }

  });
});
```

All dependencies required, I do not get any errors to the console, just the if statement doesn't find the user I created and console.log returns undefined. Am I missing here something? This doesn't make any sense. I changed callback to promises and still the same. I feel like I'm doing something wrong when looking for user in DB. I tried find({}) but no luck.

Comment: Can you find it from mongo console?

Comment: In promise based mongoose findOne, you only get the doc in the then clause. I would also recommend to use exec().

Comment: @MustafaMamun I'm using Robo 3T as a replace for mongo console, but yeah, I can see it in console too.

Comment: @tumulr where exactly I need to use it?

Comment: @Limpuls Check this http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: @tumulr I did. I searched the whole internet, I tried everything. Still not working. Here is my updated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471086/mongoose-findone-function-returns-null-undefined It's been two days, I need to move on with the project, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using user.find, What is your user variable, Where have you declared that?

You are assigning user schema model to **Usermodel**

Your query should be `Usermodel.findOne({name:req.body.name})`

Comment: Because Usermodel is in a different file called user.js, I call require it to my api.js routes document and assign it to user variable. That's where user is coming from.

Comment: I think I would get undefined error if I was using wrong variable. Now it looks like this: `var user = require("../models/user");`