# Mongoose findOne function returns null/undefined

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I always get `null`/`undefined` when fetching data from the database in my `/authenticate` route. Connection is successful and the user exists in the database (checked with Robo 3T). Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var user = require("../models/user");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {    
   user.findOne({ name: req.body.name }).then(function(foundUser) {
       if (!foundUser) { return res.status(404).send("No user matching name"); }
       return res.status(200).json(foundUser);
   });
});
```

Here is the request I'm executing from Postman:

[image]

Comment: Small note: Regarding me saying that POSTMAN is loading forever, that's not the problem I'm concerned with, I can just pass res.json(user) to the function and it returns immidiately 200OK. But the console still returns the user undefined/null.

Comment: `req.body.name` it may be null, so findOne may return null

Comment: @KalaiselvanA Yes, I tried to console.log `req.body` and it's empty object. But how can it be empty if user with these key values like "name" is sitting right there in DB? And like I said, my other routes are working with body parser. Just for the sake of it, I tried to require body parser and set middleware for it in my api.js routes file, even tho it's working anyway, but yeah, no success.

Comment: its depends on your route calling method try to use `req.params.name`

Comment: @KalaiselvanA Neither that. Like I said, in the blog article I linked to, guy is using req.body and is not even using the promises and it works for him. I assume there might be problem with the npm modules themselves

Comment: @KalaiselvanA Should I try to create GitHub issue to mongoose repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

For express to parse form data in addition to json you need to add a second body parser to your application:

```
var app = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Enable express to parse body data from raw application/json data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Enables express to parse body data from x-www-form-encoded data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: I installed and tried using bluebird, same shit. I don't see any difference in here between native promise and bluebird. I added more code of my REST API to OP, maybe if you could look at it, you would see something wrong with it.

Comment: In Postman, try changing the body content from `x-www-form-encoded` to `raw` and then choose `JSON (application/json)` in the dropdown that comes up.

Comment: Works like a charm! But wait, why `req.body.name` can't read x-www-form-encoded and how to setup it or what to use to read x-www-form-encoded instead of JSON raw?

Comment: Sweet! I'm not totally sure about this, but try adding this line 
  `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`. This will configure express to make is possible to parse the body from a form-submit aswell.

Comment: Yup, that was that. Very small detail, haven't even considered it, although at one point I was concerned with urlencoded vs raw when using POSTMAN, but didn't feel the need to change it, because I was stuck in my head that it was mongoose problem and the only, lol. Thanks a lot! If you edit your answer slightly regarding body-parser, I will accept it and it will be easier to see for others who run into similar problem

Comment: Happy to help :) I've edited the answer so it makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 0):

`req.body.name` it may be null, so `findOne()` may return null

```
var query = user.findOne({name: req.params.name});
```

its depends on your route calling method try to use `req.params.name`

Answer (score -1):

try making a test in mongo shell on your server. Print db.user.find(); and check your user

Comment: It's there. I can see in both, the shell and Robo 3T application